# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'Can't create directory

Tags: magento2, virtual

I got an error after setting localhost , accessing localhost.

my virtual host configuration is below : ServerName local.defaultMagento.com

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/Androider/defaultMagento"

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
</IfModule>

<Directory "/Users/Androider/defaultMagento">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
        RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
        RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

I searched a lot and finally found that it may be caused by the permission in virtualHostConfiguration file.

But I think what I've done is nothing wrong...

Is there anyone helping me?

Comment: Which folder is it trying to create? You probably need to set appropriate permissions on the var directory

Comment: You tagged it magento2 yet vhost config is most likely for mmagento 1.x

Answer (score 1):

This is a file permission issue. Please follow http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache-user.html#install-update-depend-user-create to set proper permissions for your filesystem and users.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the similar issue.
It was due to two or more apache running on same system.

I had installed previously wampp and then xampp. Working on xampp, magento2, i got above error.
What i did was simply uninstall wampp, restart apache of xampp and all was fine.

Hope it Helps